# Can't differentiate the variation between the two

Tags: python, web-scraping

When i run my script I can see that both print statements(as shown below) bring the desired results.

However, my question is: if i can get results using the line 8 [Title] statement (I meant, the style of usage) in my script then why should i go for the line 10 [Name] statement as you can see that a for loop has been used within.

I have seen several different scripts where the way i used in line 10 [Name] is mushrooming. Is there any difference between the two?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA"
req = requests.get(url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
Items=bsObj.findAll("div",{"class":"info"})
for product in Items:

    Title=product.findAll("a",{"class":"business-name"})[0].text
    print(Title)

    Name=[item for item in product.findAll("a",{"class":"business-name"})][0].text
    print(Name)
```

Comment: list comprehension doesn't make any sense here since [`findAll`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=findall#find-all) returns list and you are not doing anything with its elements

Comment: Your listcomp merely produces a copy  of the `findAll()` result. It is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

In the first statement the `findAll` method is returning an iterable and from that you're selecting the first item (`[0]`).
For the second with the list comprehension, you're first creating a list containing going over all the elements from the iterable, then selecting the first element again, which will produce the very same results.

BTW you can still use `find()` method or `find_all(limit=1)` instead of scanning the whole object.